# Send cookies to Webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to automatically authenticate user in `WebView`via cookies, so I need to send cookies to the `WebView`.

I'm using [PersistentCookieStore](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/loopj/android/http/PersistentCookieStore.java) class to save cookies.

I wanted to use `CookieSyncManager` class to send cookies but the doc says :

> @deprecated The WebView now automatically syncs cookies as necessary.
>    *             You no longer need to create or use the CookieSyncManager.
>    *             To manually force a sync you can use the CookieManager
>    *             method {@link CookieManager#flush} which is a synchronous
>    *             replacement for {@link #sync}.

Here my code (not working) :

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

// add cookie in WebView
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager(new PersistentCookieStore(getActivity()), CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
android.webkit.CookieManager webViewCookieManager = android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance();
List<HttpCookie> httpCookieList = cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies();
for (HttpCookie cookie : httpCookieList) {
    webViewCookieManager.setCookie(cookie.getDomain(), cookie.getValue());
}

mWebView.loadUrl(url);
```